# Two lines of text on UIButton with different fonts each

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found a way to add two lines of text on a UIButton,
but what I want is that each of these lines of texts
have different font (for instance one is bold, other not).
How is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add 2 UILabel to the UIButton as subviews.

You can do it like:

```
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40);
[self.view addSubview:testButton];

UILabel *firstLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
firstLineTestButton.text = @"First line";
firstLineTestButton.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[testButton addSubview:firstLineTestButton];

UILabel *secondLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 20)];
secondLineTestButton.text = @"Second line";
secondLineTestButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[testButton addSubview:secondLineTestButton];
```

---

---

To also make highlighting possible for the UILabels, you need to make the highlighting of the button custom.

So add the actions to the button and then check the button subviews for the labels and change their colors.

```
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self touchCancel:sender];
    /* DO SOME MORE ACTIONS */
}

-(void)changeColor:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    for( UIView *subview in sender.subviews ){
        if( [subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] ){
            UILabel *subViewLabel = (UILabel*)subview;
            subViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchCancel:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    for( UIView *subview in sender.subviews ){
        if( [subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] ){
            UILabel *subViewLabel = (UILabel*)subview;
            subViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit problematic. Now when the user selects the button, the labels remain unchanged, i.e., not highlighted etc. ?? what to do in this case? can you please help?

Comment: Simply set the `backgroundColor` property of the labels to `[UIColor clearColor]` and you should be fine

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks. What's the difference between the TouchUP and TouchDown events? thanks.

Comment: ps. Also why is this method: -(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender empty? I mean except the single line and the comment. thanks.

Comment: Touch down is called when your finger hits the screen / button. Touch up is called when your finger releases the screen / button. The buttonAction is for what you want to do when the button is pressed, like opening another view or something else.

Answer (score 8):

The solution of Roland is good, another way to do this would be to use a `NSAttributedString`. The downside is, that it only works in iOS 6 and above.

If this is not a problem, here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // We want 2 lines for our buttons' title label
    [[self.button titleLabel] setNumberOfLines:2];

    // Setup the string
    NSMutableAttributedString *titleText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This should be bold,\n and this should not."];

    // Set the font to bold from the beginning of the string to the ","
    [titleText addAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14] forKey:NSFontAttributeName] range:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];

    // Normal font for the rest of the text
    [titleText addAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] forKey:NSFontAttributeName] range:NSMakeRange(20, 22)];

    // Set the attributed string as the buttons' title text
    [self.button setAttributedTitle:titleText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. This is a problem because I need to support iOS 4.3 too. But I encountered a problem with Roland's approach, as I commented above. Maybe you know a workaround?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two UILabels as subview of the button and then can set the text of the labels as

```
[lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:18]];
[lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper animation, you should subclass `UIButton` and redraw it when its state changes.

```
(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    if (!self.firstLineTestButton) {
        self.firstLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
        self.firstLineTestButton.text = @"First line";
        self.firstLineTestButton.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [self addSubview:self.firstLineTestButton];
    } 

    if (!self.secondLineTestButton) {
        self.secondLineTestButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 20)];
        self.secondLineTestButton.text = @"Second line";
        self.secondLineTestButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [self addSubview:self.secondLineTestButton];
    }

    if (!self.highlighted) {
        // Do custom drawing such as changing text color
    } else {
        // Do custom drawing such as changing text color
    }
}
(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    // Force redraw of button
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```